# Is there any way to add a favourite button on the image?

Tags: kotlin

I'm currently working on mobile application by using the kotlin language. May I know is it possible to add a favorite button on the image that the user can click it? If it is possible, then how is it?

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
    android:id="@+id/toggleButtonGroup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ic_favorite"
        style="@style/ToggleButtonWithIconOnly"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        />

</com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/cake"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="55dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/fgh" />
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes it is possible to do something like this. What have you tried to do to complete this? I'm sorry, but there is no effort shown, this site isn't a repo for examples.

Comment: @Derek I have tried to created the button. However, I'm not sure how to move it to the left top corner of the image. I have edited the question, feel free to check it.

Comment: I suggest looking into declaring layouts to get a better understanding of them, and in turn, you will be able to build what you want. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout

I think looking closer at a relativeLayout would provide insight on what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @Derek I think I get it, but how to remove the border of the button? You may refer to the last screenshot

Comment: You should be able to use an ImageButton. I believe this might be better. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton

Comment: @Derek Ok I have use an ImageButton, but how to align it infront of the image? You may check the latest screenshot

Comment: The parent ViewGroup of the button and the ImageView would be responsible for placing one over the other. It depends what you're using. In this case, it's simple enough for FrameLayout. Give the button `layout_gravity="start|top"`